# How would I discover an operator's name?

Tags: python, scripting

Simply stated, I'm looking for the python operator for what the <kbd>P</kbd> key does to selected objects in edit mode.

So I'm looping through edges like so:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object

for e in obj.data.edges:
    print(dir(e))
```

I'm attempting to find the e.magically_separate_from_object :D but cannot find it.

Usually I'd find out how to do it through the window interface,but I can't find the window interface for <kbd>P</kbd> either.

Comment: [`bpy.ops.mesh.separate()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=separate#bpy.ops.mesh.separate)

Comment: So normally how would I independently discover that little operation without posting on stackexchange? Is there an intuitive way to find it?

Comment: If you hover over the options in the menu which appears when you press `P`, the python calls should be in the tooltip. You can also search the [api reference](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/).

Comment: We dont want to have `"python operation for..." (...every tool...)` - so question should be worded more generally. _How do I find the equivalent Python command for a key shortcut or menu item?_ ~ would be a good question.

Answer (score 3):

If you right click on nearly any button, tool, or menu item in blender there will be a link to the blender python API for that button.
[image]
Link to [blender python API](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.separate) for `bpy.ops.mesh.separate`

Answer (score 2):

if you slide down the info editor header, you will see a list of the operators as they are called, this will show you whats going on as you call operators.